# Use beautifulsoup for pick complete-set of data with specfic criteria id

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Can I filter-out all no data in `id="time_xxxxxx"` and  `id="odds_3_xxxxxx"` from all tags which contain in `<tr id="tr_xxxxxx">`, and just display all has data in  `id="time_xxxxxx"` and `id="odds_3_xxxxxx"`?

from this HTML code have one `<tr>` tag which contains `id="tr_xxxxxxx`

```html
<tr> </tr>
```

in this tag contain two set of data

```html
<td id="odds_3_xxxxxxx"></td>
<div id="time_xxxxx"> </div>
```

but I just want to get the tag which has completed set of the data which just first set of `id="odds_3_xxxxxx"` was ok.

In this html table, the data pattern are following:

1. first set (data complete-set)
2. second set (no time data)
3. third set (just has time data)

HTML:

```html
<tr style="display: none;" id="tr_976952" index="0" align="center" bgcolor="#F7F3F7" height="15">
   <div id="time_1039509">
       42 
     <img src="images/in.gif" border="0">
   </div>
   <td width="90" id="odds_3_1039509" title="">   
       <a class="sb" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(1039509,'3')">0.94</a>                            
       <img src="images/t3.gif">
   <br>
       <a class="pk" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(1039509,'3')">2.5/3</a>            
   <br>
       0.86
   </td> 

  <td width="90" id="odds_4_1234567" title="">   
       <a class="sb" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(1039509,'3')">0.12</a>                            
       <img src="images/t3.gif">
   <br>
       <a class="pk" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(1039509,'3')">3</a>            
   <br>
       0.41
   </td>
</tr>

<tr style="display: none;" id="tr_654654" index="0" align="center" bgcolor="#F7F3F7" height="15">
   <div id="time_654654">
     <img src="images/in.gif" border="0">
   </div>
   <td width="90" id="odds_3_654654" title="">   
       <a class="sb" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(654654,'3')">0.88</a>                            
       <img src="images/t3.gif">
   <br>
       <a class="pk" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(654654,'3')">1.5</a>            
   <br>
       0.86
   </td> 

  <td width="90" id="odds_4_1234567" title="">   
       <a class="sb" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(654654,'3')">0.77</a>                            
       <img src="images/t3.gif">
   <br>
       <a class="pk" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(654654,'3')">2</a>            
   <br>
       0.66
   </td>
</tr>

<tr style="display: none;" id="tr_534589" index="0" align="center" bgcolor="#F7F3F7" height="15">
   <div id="time_534589">
       50
     <img src="images/in.gif" border="0">
   </div>
  <td width="90" id="odds_3_534589" title=""></td> 
  <td width="90" id="odds_4_534589" title="">   
   <a class="sb" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(534589,'3')">0.99</a>                            
       <img src="images/t3.gif">
   <br>
       <a class="pk" href="javascript:" onclick="ChangeDetail3(534589,'3')">6</a>            
   <br>
       0.74
   </td>
</tr>
```

Code: (for my code will display all data, but I just need to complete-set of data, if the data are not in complete-set, I don't want to display)

```
rows = table.findAll("tr", {"id" : re.compile('tr_*\d')})

cols = soup.find_all(["div", "td"], id=re.compile('^(odds_3|time)_\d+$'))
data = [t.strip()
        for tag in cols
        for t in tag.find_all(text=True) if t.strip()]
print '; '.join(data)
```

Output:

```
42; 0.94 ; 2.5/3 ; 0.86 
0.88 ; 1.5 ; 0.86
50
```

Expected Output:

```
42; 0.94 ; 2.5/3 ; 0.86
```

Comment: Did you just repost this question on a new account? Don't create new accounts to avoid a question ban or other rate limits please.

Comment: You could just only print when `len(data) == 4` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just filter what gets printed like this:

```
if len(data) == 4:
    print '; '.join(data)
```

Comment: can I put the print out time after join(data) ? like 42; 0.94 ; 2.5/3 ; 0.86 ; 11:07:00 ; 08/16/2014